# How to use generics in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am fixing some bugs in an old React application. It doesn't have typescript.

To use Select2 component (Blueprintjs library), I must convert it to a non-generic reference.

In Typescript, it can be achieved with `const FilmSelect = Select2.ofType<Films.Film>();`

My attempt: `Select2.ofType<PropTypes.array>()` didn't work.

How can I achieve the same result with Javascript only (no typescript)?

Below is an example using typescript.

```
import { Button } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { MenuItem2 } from "@blueprintjs/popover2";
import { Select2 } from "@blueprintjs/select";
import * as Films from "./films";
 
// Select2<T> is a generic component to work with your data types.
// In TypeScript, you must first obtain a non-generic reference:
const FilmSelect = Select2.ofType<Films.Film>();
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <FilmSelect
        items={Films.items}
        itemPredicate={Films.itemPredicate}
        itemRenderer={Films.itemRenderer}
        noResults={<MenuItem2 disabled={true} text="No results."  roleStructure="listoption" />}
        onItemSelect={...}
    >
        {/* children become the popover target; render value here */}
        <Button text={Films.items[0].title} rightIcon="double-caret-vertical" />
    </FilmSelect>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Comment: Typescript doesn't affect a code execution. So `const FilmSelect = Select2.ofType();` should work.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I am getting an error -  FilmSelect is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation of [Blueprint](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select2):

> In TypeScript, `Select2<T>` is a generic component so you must define a local type that specifies `<T>`, the type of one item in `items`. The props on this local type will now operate on your data type (speak your language) so you can easily define handlers without transformation steps, but most props are required as a result. The static `Select2.ofType<T>()` method is available to streamline this process. **(Note that this has no effect on JavaScript usage: the `Select2` export is a perfectly valid React component class.)**

You can just write:

```
import { Button } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { MenuItem2 } from "@blueprintjs/popover2";
import { Select2 as FilmSelect  } from "@blueprintjs/select";
import * as Films from "./films";

ReactDOM.render(
    <FilmSelect
        items={Films.items}
        itemPredicate={Films.itemPredicate}
        itemRenderer={Films.itemRenderer}
        noResults={<MenuItem2 disabled={true} text="No results."  roleStructure="listoption" />}
        onItemSelect={...}
    >
        {/* children become the popover target; render value here */}
        <Button text={Films.items[0].title} rightIcon="double-caret-vertical" />
    </FilmSelect>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the console -                                                                           The above error occurred in the <Blueprint4.QueryList> component:

QueryList@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blueprintjs/select/lib/esm/components/query-list/queryList.js:42:24

Comment: The error is coming from here - https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/select/src/components/query-list/queryList.tsx#L156

Comment: @DamienAsseya But what does the error say?